# Flask: In development, how can I achieve dynamic routing for media assets?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask to develop a simple web application.

I have static media assets (photographs, PDFs etc) inside `files/folder/subfolder/asset[.pdf|.jpg]`. But I want the URL to the files to look like this: `files/folder_subfolder_asset[.pdf|jpg]`. As you can see, the real `path` is coded in the `filename`.

`folder` and `subfolder` are different for each image. There are a lot of images!

On **production**, on the **server**, I will be handling the serving of the files with [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/), how can I accomplish something similar on **development**?

Note: on **development** I'm using `Flask run` to test the application. Please advice if I need to use something different.

Comment: try with [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/)

Comment: @Tiny.D I read the documentation of Blueprints but can't figure out how to use them to serve the image. Want to provide an example? :)

Comment: Split `folder_subfolder_asset[.pdf|jpg]` and `send_static_file` from `folder/subfolder/asset[.pdf|.jpg]`. But i'm not familiar nginx and don't know how to achieve this in nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with (Application Objects or Blueprint Objects, [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/)) :

- `static_url_path` – can be used to specify a different path for the static files on the web. Defaults to the name of the `static_folder` folder.
- `static_folder` – the folder with static files that should be served at `static_url_path`. Defaults to the 'static' folder in the root path of the application.

eg:

Your could set `static_foler` to static file directory: `/files/folder/subfolder/asset`, and `static_url_path` to `/files/folder_subfolder_asset`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='files/folder/subfolder/asset/', static_url_path='/files/folder_subfolder_asset')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def root():
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='figure.jpeg'))   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, it will redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/files/folder_subfolder_asset/figure.jpeg`, the `url` was change to the one defined in `static_url_path`

Comment: Man. I'm so sorry, I forgot to mention the `folder` and `subfolder` are always different for each image. That's why I asked the question. I will edit it as soon as possible.